# CSS margin and values

Tags: css, html

Last day I asked a question and someone answered that I want, it is here: http://jsfiddle.net/dmrc1143/Cf2k8/

According to it I started to do my `CSS`. But I cannot put my `wrapper_top` to center. Everytime It must be center. What is wrong in my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/dmrc1143/VK23u/
(forget ASP.NET elements.)

My second question: I used `float:right;` and how can I do without `float:right;` ? And is `float:right;`  bad? I read somewhere It shows you are a beginner, is it right?

Comment: Floating right is fine, it does not show that you are a beginner. Just don't use tables.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, centering via `margin: auto;` works only for static positioned elements.
You can check by simple erasing the line `position: fixed;` which should give you the desired result.
A possible solution to apply it on fixed positioned elements would be to center via `left: 50%` and `margin-left` to half of the element's size.